# Brainfuck interpreter in C, looking for improvements on the looping functionality

Tags: c, interpreter, brainfuck, c11

I've just started to get into PL design and made a simple Brainfuck interpreter. Although it is functional,  I don't feel too confident on the execution, particularly the implementation for loops, I read some other bf interpreters and they generally used stacks for looping, but I didn't knew how to implement one ._.
Anyway, I', **beyond** open to constructive criticism on how to improve this code.

Also note the the macros `COL_RED_BLK` and `COL_END` are ansii escape code sequences to add to flare to the error messages and that I'm using C11 as the standard, since it's the one that I prefer the most.

```
int interpret(char * tape, size_t size);
char * loadTape(const char filename[], size_t * tape_size);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "%s: <file> \n"
            "Input File required \n",
            argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    size_t tape_sz = 0;
    char * tape = loadTape(argv[1], &tape_sz);
    // load the input file into a string
    if (!tape) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%sError:%s loading the file to the tape.\n",
            COL_RED_BLK, COL_END);
    }
    
    interpret(tape, tape_sz);
    
    free(tape);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int interpret(char * tape, size_t size)
{
    size_t cond = 0,
        loop_s = 0,
        et_pos = 0;
    char et[size];
    memset(&et, 0, size);
    // executable tape
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        switch (tape[i]) {
        case (OP_ADD): ++et[et_pos]; break;
        case (OP_SUB): --et[et_pos]; break;
        case (MV_INC):
            if (et_pos + 1 < size) {
                ++et_pos;
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "%sError:%s tape overrun in instruction %zu\n",
                    COL_RED_BLK, COL_END, i+1);
                return 1;
            }
            break;          
        case (MV_DEC):
            if (et_pos != 0) {
                --et_pos;
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "%sError:%s tape underrun in instrunction %zu\n",
                    COL_RED_BLK, COL_END, i+1);
                return 1;
            }
            break;
        case (LOOP_S):
            cond = et_pos;
            loop_s = i;
            break;
        case (LOOP_E):
            if (et[cond]) {
                et_pos = cond;
                i = loop_s;
            }
            break;
        case (IO_INP): et[et_pos] = getchar(); break;
        case (IO_OUT): putchar(et[et_pos]); break;          
        default: break; // brainfuck comment or empty space
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

An example program is of course `Hello World`

```
-[------->+<]>-.
-[->+++++<]>++.
+++++++..
+++.
[--->+<]>-----.
---[->+++<]>.
-[--->+<]>---.
+++.
------.
--------.
hello world
```

Comment: Adding a `main` with a sample call/test case would be useful.

Comment: The main issue I see is that you don't support nested loops.

Comment: @MartinYork, yes, this is the single biggest crutch of this interpreter, this is why people use stacks for their loops, I will implement them once I figure how they work in general, but for the time being, the interpreter is very limited.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it contains code that doesn't quite work as intended. Lack of support for nested loops is a pretty glaring deficiency, and there's no way to meaningfully review this code, especially when the poster asks to focus on the looping functionality, when looping functionality is not correctly implemented.

Comment: @200_success I think I may, the lack of nested loops do is crippling for anything

Comment: (en.wikipedia on ANSI: `Not to be confused with ASCII.`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issues

You don't support nested loops.

As you point out in the description, you need a stack to support nested loops. The easiest way to get one is to move to C++ as a language and use a [std::stack](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/). The rest of the code would be very similar.

But lets say you want to stick with C.

Here is the most trivial of stack implementations.

```
 size_t  stack[255];
 size_t  stackP = 0;

 void    push(size_t s) {stack[stackP++] = s;}
 size_t  top()          {return stack[stackP - 1];}
 void    pop()          {--stackP;}
```

No error checking or anything. But it will serve your purpose for a version 1.

---

Don't be lazy:

```
    size_t cond = 0,
        loop_s = 0,
        et_pos = 0;
```

You are making the reader work harder to understand the types. One variable per line with its type.

```
    size_t cond = 0;
    size_t loop_s = 0;
    size_t et_pos = 0;
```

---

```
    char et[size];
    memset(&et, 0, size);
```

You can achieve the same like this:

```
    char et[size] = {0};
```

---

You have this test:

```
            if (et_pos + 1 < size) {
```

And this test:

```
            if (et_pos != 0) {
```

Why not make them the same form to ease reading:

```
            if (et_pos != size) {
      // STUFF
            if (et_pos != 0) {
```

---

TO support nested loops. You need a stack.

```
        case (LOOP_S):
            cond = et_pos;
            loop_s = i;
            break;
```

Here you would simply push the value on to the stack:

```
        case (LOOP_S):
            push(i);     // Note. Restore this location as the position.
                         //       The for loop increment will automatically
                         //       take it to the first instruction in the loop.
            break;
```

Also I think it is a bug to restore the place on the tape. So saving the tape location is not useful.

```
            cond = et_pos;
```

---

Conversely to support the end of loop:

```
        case (LOOP_E):
            if (et[cond]) {
                et_pos = cond;
                i = loop_s;
            }
            break;
```

Should look more like this:

```
        case (LOOP_E):
            if (et[cond]) {
                i = top();    // Jump to the saved loop location
            } else {
                pop();        // Remove the loop position.
            }
            break;
```

---

Comment: Ok, so, make some general readability improvements, and add the stack which loads the position of i in it, depending on `cond`, it alters i or lets it continue. Thank you :)

Comment: Apparently, it is not a good idea to try to code without getting breakfast, I cannot believe that I couldn't implement a stack after two years of coding in C, sometimes I cannot believe myself. Anyways, thanks again, the interpreter works fine, now I can start adding more features to the program itself, thanks :-)